#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'JSON NULL,
soy nuevo en la programación y base de datos y estaba haciendo un mini sistema de carga de archivos con ticket pero al momento de querer agregar mi DB al phpmyadmin me da el siguiente error

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'JSON NULL,
ticket VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
fecha TIMESTAMP DEFAULT' en la linea 7

La base de datos que cree es esta:
    CREATE TABLE solicitudes (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    tipo_solicitud VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    telefono VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    descripcion TEXT NOT NULL,
    archivos JSON NULL,
    ticket VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    fecha TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    estado ENUM('Pendiente', 'Respondido') DEFAULT 'Pendiente',
    respuesta TEXT NULL
    );

Ya revise en el foro otras consultas similares y en google no encontre nada. Cualquier ayuda estaré agradecido.

En que versión de MYSQL estas trabajando? Por que al parecer es antigua o algo asi

Por defecto permite null, entonces, no es necesario agregar el JSON NULL
  CREATE TABLE solicitudes (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
tipo_solicitud VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
telefono VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
descripcion TEXT NOT NULL,
archivos JSON,
ticket VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
fecha TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
estado ENUM('Pendiente', 'Respondido') DEFAULT 'Pendiente',
respuesta TEXT
);


No parece el motivo. La consulta que hizo el OP funciona bien en un MySQL 8 y MariaDB 10.4 que tengo locales. Es probable que su BD (y/o phpmyadmin) sea de una versión que no soporta el tipo JSON.
